# Single taxonomy for different custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates, taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I have two custom post types: **books** and **authors**. Both of them have attached a custom taxonomy - **genres**.

How would I display the *books* in the **fiction** *genre*?

**What would be the URL used and the name of the template?**

I can think of two methods to do this, but they have disadvantages, so I'm looking for a method that that would be similar with WP template hierarchy: visiting **site.com/genre/fiction/** would call this template **taxonomy-genre.php**

---

**Method 1**: using custom page templates
I would create a custom page template, **cpt-genre.php**. Then, I would create an empty page for each genre in books, using slugs like **books-fiction** and so on. In the template, I'd read the slug of the page, interpret it and query to get the *books* in **fiction** *genre*.
***Result:*** accessing **site.com/books-fiction** would get to **cpt-genre.php**, and the template would display the data based on the slug of the page.
***Downside:*** difficult to administer

---

**Method 2**: add a query string to the the taxonomy URL, read it in taxonomy-books.php and taxonomy-authors.php and modify WP_Query to display only the books / authors in the mentioned genre.
***Result:*** accessing **site.com/books/?genre=fiction** would get to **taxonomy-books.php**, and the template would display the data based on the query string.
***Downside:*** the URL is not clean and, also, it's not SEO friendly

---

So, any other ideas for new methods or, at least, for ways to mitigate the downsides of the above methods?

Comment: this might help https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are searching for... You must use both post_type and tax_query to filter your query

```
 $query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'books',          // name of post type.
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'fiction',   // taxonomy name
        )
    )
) );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    // do stuff here....
endwhile;

/**
 * reset the orignal query
 * we should use this to reset wp_query
 */
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Great code, it would work on a custom page template, for instance, but nothing similar to using **taxonomy-genre.php** to display **site.com/genre/fiction**.
I am amending my initial question with this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, do you need to display just the authors per genre?

If not, then you can hook on `pre_get_posts` and just remove the author post type from the query's post types (or re-set the whole thing to books) when `is_tax( 'genre' )` is true.

Comment: Yes, I also need a page for the authors in a genre. Your solution would be great if I did not need that.